# Developing SAML with outside vendor

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm looking for some advice on best practices here.  I have a SAML framework built into my application.  Typically what I've done to test it is have two instances of Visual Studio running, each on a different port and then make calls from localhost:50000 to localhost:330000 or whatever port number it is.

The issue with this is that I can't test with HTTPS and real certificates that require it.  The advice that I'm looking for here is how other people have tackled this in the past.

If I want to test with HTTPS, my thinking is I'd have to set up an IIS websites and use those with each other.  If I wanted to test in with an outside vendor, I'd have to open up a port in our firewall, and point it to my computer.

Is this the best way to go about doing this?  I'm not sure it is, so I wanted to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

A easier and more flexible way might be to set up your host file to recognize a real URL as your local host.

```
127.0.0.1 www.testIDP.com
127.0.0.1 www.testSP.com
```

Then you [configure your own CA using OpenSSL](http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2013/08/creating-your-own-ca-with-openssl-and_23.html) and issue ssl certificates from it.

Lastly you add a trust to your own CA in your application. I guess there is some CA truststor in the .Net framework you use.